# Are there tours available from Seoul to the Korean Demilitarized Zone?

Tags: tours, south-korea, seoul

I am planning to visit the Korean Demilitarized Zone while staying in Seoul and would like to get tour options. Anyone has done this?

Prices, schedule and tips are most welcome.

Comment: This is the #1 thing for western tourists to do on short trips to South Korea. It's not far north from Seoul. Every accommodation will have brochures for the tours that they expect to arrange for the majority of their guests. Oddly, though I've been to South Korea seven times I didn't visit the DMZ yet.

Comment: FYI: [Can I go to the Korean Demilitarized Zone (DMZ) by myself?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65183/1810)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 2 sample companies organizing these trips as a group tour:

- [Koridoor](http://www.koridoor.co.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=travelInfo&sca=JSA/DMZ)
- [Panmunjom](http://koreadmztour.com/en/index.asp)

There are several different places to see, such as the DMZ with its fences, some tunnels and the border crossings of course. Because of the many different combination of locations that you can see in a half-day or full-day course, the prices also vary a lot, between 40-100 USD.

If you want to have something more personalized, you can also [arrange a private guide](http://www.koreaprivatetours.com/tours/tag/dmz-tour/), but of course the price will be in a different dimension (up to 500 USD/person, less if there are more people).

There is also the option of being [guided by a local](http://www.toursbylocals.com/DMZSpyTour) instead of a professional guide. The price of 450 USD for a 8 hour is for a whole group.

If you read the descriptions, you will see that some of them involve hiking, some are very short and others take a whole day. So I would suggest you decide how much time you want to spend and how much money to make a selection.

Comment: I would be extremely cautious of any "local" tours of the DMZ. In general, Korean citizens are NOT allowed within the main parts of the DMZ that you would want to visit. The specifically linked entry appears to be simply the standard bus trip to the DMZ, combined with a hike in the hills near the border. Consider the fact that this border is the most heavily fortified border in the world (including landmines, etc), and then decide if hiking in the mountains near it is a good idea!

Comment: I'd add the USO Tour to Panmunjom (JSA) to that (http://affiliates.uso.org/Korea/default.cfm?contentid=347). I went with them in 2011 and it was perfect.