# Can I go to the Korean Demilitarized Zone (DMZ) by myself?

Tags: south-korea, north-korea

I wonder whether I can go to and visit the [Korean Demilitarized Zone (DMZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Demilitarized_Zone) by myself, i.e., without some tour operator.

I am mostly interested in the 3rd tunnel, and its neighboring sites such as Imjingak Park, the Unification Bridge, the DMZ theater and exhibition hall, the Dora Observatory, Dorasan Station, the Unification Village, the Amethyst Center, and the Joint Security Area.

[image]

Can I simply drive there, park the car and look around? If that matters, I have the French nationality.

I plan to stay on the South Korean side.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Panmunjeom) it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: I don't think you can **walk** alone in North Korea

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta Sure I meant the South Korean side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can park at the Imjingak pavilion / Imjingak Pyeonghoa-Nuri Parking lot:

[image]

It costs around 2 USD for the full day.

The number of tourists has recently [decreased](http://www.kyeongin.com/main/view.php?key=20160218010005977) due to recent North vs South tensions, so hopefully it should be easy to park.

After you park, you can purchase an [entrance ticket](http://blog.naver.com/lunasworld/220473501769), which comprises shuttle (without which you cannot cross the bridge between the parking lot and dora station) and mini-train:

[image]

Only the access to [Panmunjeom](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Panmunjeom) (which includes the [Joint Security Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Security_Area)) requires some authorized toured guide ([example 1](http://www.panmunjomtour.com/), [example 2](http://www.dmztours.com/seoul_dmz_tours.htm), [example 3](http://www.koridoor.co.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=travelInfo&wr_id=221)).

(Disclaimer: <strike>I haven't tried it yet, will do in 2 months</strike> I successfully did it in May 2016)

---

Some maps to locate the main areas of interest:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/DMZ+-+The+Third+Tunnel/@37.893818,126.7197919,3198m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x357cf3ffd1d6cd15:0xcf70c335978ba782!6m1!1e1):

[image]

[image]